# Does anyone know what this encoding format for passwords is? I think it is a decimal array but I can't seem to convert it

Tags: passwords, hash, encoding

During a penetration test, I ran across a server that was storing passwords in its database in what seems to be a binary array of sorts:

```
password_table

1,12,12,12,122,21,13,00,00,00,000
11,112,443,12,31,09,100
110,1123,108,117,108,62,62
```

(slightly edited for confidentiality)

I've additionally managed to obtain a password `fellfa` to correspond to `1,09,10,81,15,11,51,09,000`. The range of numbers seems to span 000 all the way up to 128.

Some of the lines don't even match up properly when split into triplets and some contain large numbers that don't fit in to the ascii charset even with offsets (`45,119,142` for instance).

The server in question is a Tomcat server and the application is running a Java program. I considered that this might be a array of sorts but I can't seem to convert these arrays into anything readable or usable. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Assuming there were no numbers higher than 127 and you didn't change the number of elements, these look like 32 ascii characters, not even full bytes. This is likely a not-so-good transform (I dare not call it a hash) of the password. Hard to tell. If you've been given access to the system as part of the test, try creating a new user with a known password and see what ends up being stored.

Comment: Interesting - though there are some below 32 decimal in there as well (including 00 / NUL), so not straight ascii or a short-range transform thereof. The transform would have to be a significant one - or else it's something else entirely.

Comment: @Marc So I did some more prodding and I was able to reset a password to the value of 'fellfa' that corresponds to "1,09,10,81,15,11,51,09,000" ... still lost though.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams I just updated my Q with more info

Comment: @Marc Maybe the commas are a formatting error when I'm pulling them? It seems to be quite mixed...

Comment: Yeah, I think the commas may be extraneous somehow - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The commas appear to be somewhat unrelated. When the commas are removed, most of the digits are in groups of three.

At first, it looks like a shifted ASCII substitution, just as Marc suggested - but with some variation:

```
109 = f (102 ASCII +7)
108 = e (101 ASCII +7)
115 = l (108 ASCII +7)
115 = l (108 ASCII +7)
109 = f (102 ASCII +7)
000 = a (???)
```

Note especially that the numbers are the same distance from each other than the letters themselves are in an ASCII table, but just shifted by 7 positions.

(But even when divided into triplets, your original posted passwords don't quite match - but that may be because of the obfuscation.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be very close to whatever they're doing, but not everything matches up. Several of these strings cant be split up into perfect triplets and even if I do, the numbers are extremely large? For example `45,119,104,115,124,121,124,42`

Comment: That looks like the same scheme - 45 and 42 are 7 higher than ASCII symbols & and #, respectively, and the rest are lower-case like the above. In general, it appears as though there's something variable about where the commas are inserted, but that's something you'll have to figure out looking at the larger set of data.